# I have a link to my terms and conditions data and I want to show this data by reading it

Tags: iphone, xcode, url

How do I read data from an USL link, and display it on my textview? The URL link content contains only normal text

I am using:

```
NSString *userAgreementStringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/requestConfigurationData.php?ownerID=%@&view=userAgreement", serverURL, ownerID];
NSURL *userAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:userAgreementStringURL];
NSURLRequest *userAgreementRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:userAgreementURL];
userAgreementData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
userAgreementConnection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:userAgreementRequest delegate:self] retain];  

[userAgreementTextView setText:[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"http://medicinephone.com/dev2/visit/requestConfigurationData.php?ownerID=13&view=userAgreement" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[myTextView setText:[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]]];
```

one line of code, thank you apple.

Edit: forgot to make a NSURL from the string.

Comment: is giving warning like incompatable types

Answer (score 0):

Show us your code. If you are trying what I think you are trying passing an array to text view's `setText` method won't work. You need to get the string from the array prior to that. If you array contains one word per array element you might want to try using `componentsJoinedByString`.

Comment: [userAgreementTextView setText:[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"http://medicinephone.com/dev2/visit/requestConfigurationData.php?ownerID=13&view=userAgreement" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]];

Comment: And what error are you getting exactly? Theoretically it should work.